# How to change initial directory I want?

Tags: install4j

I added "Configure Form Components".
and then I added "Installation directory chooser".

I want to change initial directory when I click button "search" in Initialization script.
It is default of "My document".
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial installation directory can be set with

```
context.setInstallationDirectory(...)
```

before the screen is shown, for example in a "Run script" action in the "Startup" node of the installer. The directory chooser of the "Installation directory chooser" form component shows the parent directory of the current installation directory first.

Comment: thank but I mean when I click "search" button, I want  to change initial directory instead of "my document"

Comment: That is currently not supported. You can do this with the "Directory chooser" form component, it has an "Initial browser directory" property (new in 5.1.2).